# Is it possible to have 2 nodehandlers for a single node

Tags: ros, rosnode, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was checking one of the [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/3274/how-to-add-a-subscriber-in-keyboard-teleop) posed in this forum where there was an incomplete code that has 2 node_handlers in a single code. Though i see its wrong in that particular code. i am curious to know if any such situation would arise where this possibility comes.
As for as i know 1 node should have 1 node_handler. Correct me if i am wrong.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12375/is-it-possible-to-have-2-nodehandlers-for-a-single-node/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If, for example, you had:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::NodeHandle private_nh("~");
```

Then, `nh.getParam()` would look in the global namespace for a parameter, whereas `private_nh.getParam()` would look in a private namespace.

This configuration (one global, one private) is most common situation in which I use multiple NodeHandles.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-16**:
Thanks!! That makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can have as many node handles as you want, but they will all represent the same node.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-16**:
can you quote an example where i may have many instead of just one. Thanks